# Count how many objects in array do not understand it

Tags: javascript

I have this code, and it works but I have trouble understanding it, will someone help me?

```
(count[markers[i].group] = count[markers[i].group] + 1 || 1 ;)
```

what does  `+ 1` mean and `|| 1` ? What does this do in a easy whey to understand.

I have this code, and it works but I have trouble understanding it, will someone help me?

```js
const markers = [
  {
    type: "Chocolate",
    name: "KitKat",
    group: "candy",
    icon: "candy",
    coords: [5246, 8980]
  },
  {
    type: "Fruit",
    name: "Orange",
    group: "fruits",
    icon: "fruis",
    coords: [9012, 5493]
  },
  {
    type: "Fruit",
    name: "Banana",
    group: "fruits",
    icon: "fruis",
    coords: [9012, 5493]
  },
  {
    type: "Food",
    name: "Rice",
    group: "foods",
    icon: "foods",
    coords: [6724, 9556]
  },
  {
    type: "Food",
    name: "Meat",
    group: "foods",
    icon: "foods",
    coords: [6724, 9556]
  },
  {
    type: "Food",
    name: "Beam",
    group: "foods",
    icon: "foods",
    coords: [6724, 9556]
  },
  {
    type: "Liquid",
    name: "Water",
    group: "liquids",
    icon: "liquids",
    coords: [6724, 9556]
  },
  {
    type: "Liquid",
    name: "Coffe",
    group: "liquids",
    icon: "liquids",
    coords: [6724, 9556]
  }
];

var count = {}

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  count[markers[i].group] = count[markers[i].group] + 1 || 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Java and Javascript are different, Java does not use `const`.

Answer (score 0):

This is creating a count for the number of items in each group.

So `var count = {}` initialises the object

then as the for loop runs it counts the relative markers group value.

the "+ 1 || 1 " section sets `count[markers[i].group]` equal to 1 if it is the first time that group is found, or adds 1 to the previous value

Comment: can you replace it with something else?

Comment: what do you mean? if you're trying to count something else you can change the "group" to another of the objects keys

Comment: I was just wondering if  "+ 1 || 1 " can be replaced with something else that does the same? :) I am new to coding

Comment: In this instance the answer you have here is fine, why did you want to change it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if you re-write the code as the following. The code loops through each marker in the array, and stores the count of each group in another array.

```
var currentGroupCount, currentGroup;
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    currentGroup = markers[i].group;
    currentGroupCount = count[currentGroup];
    count[currentGroup] = (currentGroupCount + 1) || 1 ;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. The code you provided is written in javascript. You can embed javascript inside html with <script> tags.